# How to find out what Javascript code is run after a specific event happens on a web page?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, firebug

There's this web site for which I'd like to write a bookmarklet. To do this, I need to find out what Javascript code is run when certain links are clicked. The links are in the form `<a href="#" class="i-am-special">Do something</a>`, so there's no `onclick` attribute for me to see what code is run.

So how do I accomplish this goal? I imagine I need to use a browser addon like Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in Chrome.

Sorry if this has been answered before.

Comment: Have you tried searching the source for the class/id?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebug for Firefox or Chrome's builtin DOM/JavaScript console to look for event listeners. It will give you the function call/name, search the code for this name...